Prometheus Service Discovery in Kubernetes - Scrape LoadBalancer Ingress Label
I am using the Prometheus Helm chart in my Kubernetes cluster to monitor services. However, I am unable to get Prometheus to discover or scrape the LoadBalancer Ingress field of a Kubernetes service.
Here is the configuration of the service:
Name:                     postgres-xyz-postgresql-primary
Namespace:                xyz
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=primary
                      app.kubernetes.io/instance=postgres-app
                      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                      app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql
                      app.kubernetes.io/version=17.0.0
                      helm.sh/chart=postgresql-16.0.1
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: postgres-app
                      meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: xyz
Selector:                               app.kubernetes.io/component=primary,app.kubernetes.io/instance=postgres-   app,app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack  
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       
IPs:                      
LoadBalancer Ingress:     aoo000nnbbgghhsdfg-182496858.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:                     tcp-postgresql  5432/TCP
 TargetPort:               tcp-postgresql/TCP
 NodePort:                 tcp-postgresql  32599/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.91.92:5432
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster

In my Prometheus scrape configuration, I am using the following job for service discovery:
- job_name: 'kubernetes-services'
  honor_labels: true

  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    module: [http_2xx]

 kubernetes_sd_configs:
   - role: service

 relabel_configs:
   - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe]
     action: keep
     regex: true
   - source_labels: [__address__]
     target_label: __param_target
   - target_label: __address__
     replacement: blackbox
   - source_labels: [__param_target]
     target_label: instance
   - action: labelmap
     regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
   - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
     target_label: namespace
   - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
     target_label: service

The scrape job does not seem to capture the LoadBalancer Ingress field.
I tried adding the following to the relabel_configs to map the LoadBalancer Ingress to a custom label (loadbalancer_ingress):
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_external_dns_hostname]
  target_label: loadbalancer_ingress

However, this doesn't seem to capture the LoadBalancer Ingress value
Questions:

How can I modify the Prometheus relabel_configs to include the LoadBalancer Ingress field for scraping?

Is there a specific label or field in the kubernetes_sd_configs that maps to the LoadBalancer Ingress field?

Do I need a separate configuration to target LoadBalancer services explicitly?


Additional Info:
Kubernetes version: 1.30
Prometheus Helm chart version: prometheus-26.0.0
Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!



How can I modify the Prometheus relabel_configs to include the LoadBalancer Ingress field for scraping?
Is there a specific label or field in the kubernetes_sd_configs that maps to the LoadBalancer Ingress field?


According to Prometheus service sd config, the LoadBalancer Ingress isn't include as a meta field that will be scraped by Prometheus, the thing that can be scraped is IP field.
I don't think you could scrape address from Ingress resource either.
I believe what you're trying to do is differentiate metrics by AWS's ELB hostname? The hostname of the ELB is generated for you every time you create an Ingress resources so setting a hard code will not be possible.
Maybe using AWS Load Balancer Controller's annotations such as alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name on Service or alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name on Ingress and configure Prometheus to scrape that annotation might be better?
You'd get to identify the load balancer created by AWS with name, while not have to worry about which hostname AWS will generated for you.
